# Using vertex colors and textures in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, vertex

I am familiar with texture usage in OpenGL. I am also familiar with the coloring and interpolation of colors between vertices. Can the two be used in conjunction with one another? Does doing so tint the texture with the color supplied at each vertex? I am rendering an older game format which supplies both so I am trying to figure out if they both work in conjunction to create variations for the textures.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that. If you set the colour on a vertex to anything other than white, the texture that is applied will be filtered by the colour given. If different vertices on the same polygon have different colours, and there are textures, the colours will be interpolated exactly the same as for no textures.

Comment: Note that how the texture combines with the vertex color is *entirely* dependent on the texture environment setting (`glTexEnv`) for that texture unit. So it may "be filtered" by default, but other settings can cause different effects (adding, etc).

Comment: In particular, `GL_MODULATE` will tell the render engine to multiply the texture colors by the vertex colors as described in @Jarryd's answer.  `GL_DECAL` cause the texture to be blended with the vertex colors which is also useful (as when applying decals!)  Modulate to colorize the texture per vertex colors, decal to apply the texture over the top of a colored surface, with surface showing through the transparent parts of the texture.